# Software update notifier

Tags: notifications, releases

Is there a service/software where I can subscribe to/create notifications for releases of specific software packages such as Git or JDK? Necessary features would be free as in beer, updates fetched from the official web site (in other words, no third party repositories), and the possibility to create my own searches. Nice features would be existing notifications for well-known software, free as in freedom, and notifications with either email or web feeds.

I need to know of the release of the **sources** to compile into a custom package.

Comment: Source releases directly from the developers. This will be difficult. Your best bet is probably some generic "monitor a website" solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No acceptable solutions found; using home-brewed solution. :/

Answer (score 0):

For OS X, I'd suggest creating an [iusethis](http://osx.iusethis.com) profile and subscribing to your personal RSS feed. It's not easily extensible though, and some update notifications are, as far as I know, by third parties. Nevertheless, it works quite well and with [AppFresh](http://metaquark.de/appfresh/) there's a convenient client application.

Comment: Good idea, but a quick test revealed that the Git versions have not been updated since September. I guess this is the last version in OS X, but that means it's not actually fetching from the supplier.

Comment: @l0b0 There's a release on the website ("Git OSX Installer") from Jan 10 -- I submitted a new version to iusethis. I know that AppFresh uses Sparkle appcast feed URLs to find out about newer versions, and reports them back to iusethis. Maybe Git OSX doesn't use Sparkle.